# Health going down every 3 seconds while player is on enemy

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

I'm making a game in ActionScript 3, essentially I'm trying to make it so when the character (Malcolm1) touches the enemy (Leaf1) the Health goes down by 1, however I only want this to happen if it has been 3 seconds since Malcolm1 has last hit Leaf1, this is so he gets like a 3 second immunity, so his health doesn't just instantly go down, here is my code right now:

```
 Malcolm1.addEventListener( Event.ENTER_FRAME, leafhitmalcolm) function
 leafhitmalcolm( e:Event ):void {
     if(Malcolm1.hitTestObject(Leaf1))
     {
         Health = (Health - 1)  
     }  
 }
```

How could I make it so it has to be at least 3 seconds since they last collided to make health go down?

Answer (score 0):

Conceptually, you want to make your character temporarily invincible immediately after a hit. To do this you can set a counter to 3 seconds (3 * frameRate) every time your character is hit, then decrement it each frame until it reaches 0, and only register a hit when it is 0.

```
var hitDelay:int = 0;
function leafhitmalcom(e:Event):void {
    if(hitDelay > 0) {
        hitDelay--;
    } else if(Malcolm1.hitTestObject(Leaf1)) {
        Health--;
        hitDelay = 3 * frameRate;
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you could use a timer of 3000 milliseconds in a similar way:

```
var recovering:Boolean = false;
function leafhitmalcom(e:Event):void {
    // Only check for a hit if not currently recovering from a hit
    if(recovering == false && Malcom1.hitTestObject(Leaf1)){
        Health--;
        recovering = true;
        setTimeout(recover, 3000);
    }
}
function recover():void {
    recovering = false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are answering your own question: make him immune for 3 seconds is the solution.

As it's malcolm's helath that should be reduced, health should be a property of malcolm and not some standalone variable.

Create a class `Malcolm`.
Create a setter function for health that either accepts the damage or not:
If there's no Timer running, deal the damage and start a Timer that runs for 3 seconds.
If there's a Timer running, ignore the damage.

Answer (score 0):

Use a TimerEvent which gets triggered when Malcolm hits a leaf. Inside the timerevent have a shield boolean variable and set it to true. The timer should be set for 3 seconds (3000 milliseconds). So as long as the shield is true (i.e.) for 3 seconds Malcolm cannot be harmed. Have a TimerEvent.COMPLETE which gets called after 3 seconds and here set your shield variable to false. This way you can get your 3 seconds of invincibility